# Better way placing images in row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want place two images in one row, and add 10px spacing between them.
Since layout is responsive, the row should break on mobile screen and images should go one above the other.

Sample [layout](http://www.cssdesk.com/cnSm6)

I use just two images without extra code, it works, but there definitely should be better, more reliable way, using div containers that also allowing to add aligning to images(I need vertical-align:middle). What is better CSS to achieve this, specifically for this layout?

Comment: Will you always have two images or are you looking for a more general solution for 3 or more images?  Is there a maximum width to the images?  Please comment, thank you!

Comment: There will be 1 or 2 images maximum. If use one image, then width usually no more 500px, if two images, the total width no more 700px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you. 
   Place the images inside a div with a width of 50%. To add the padding you can use box-sizing: border-box;

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="left ">
            <img src="http://www.codewithsonia.com/stuff/img/vader.jpg"  />
        </div>
        <div class="right ">     
            <img src="http://www.codewithsonia.com/stuff/img/vader.jpg"  />
        </div>
</div>
```

Make the images responsive by setting max-width to 100%

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;    
}

.left{
    width:50%;   
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-right:5px solid green;  
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;       

}

.right{
    width:50%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    float: right;
    border-left:5px solid red;  
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;

}

.row:after {    
        clear: both;
  }

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .right {
    width:100%;
   border-left:0; 
    clear:right;
   }    
    .left{
    width:100%;
     border-right:0; 
    clear:right;
   } 
}
```

You can see a fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/f4bt5Lq0/1/

Comment: Can I float: left both divs? Also, can be used padding or margin for spacing, or this require setting border size properties for both images?

Comment: 1) Yes, you can float them both left.2)You should use border because the size of the margin or padding will be added to the widht of the div making it bigger tant 50%.
However, if you wan to use padding or margins there is another approach you can use another approach: set a max-size for the row (let's say max-size: 1000px). Then add the padding to the left and right divs 5px for each and set the with to something arround 49.3%  -49.5%

http://jsfiddle.net/5h1t4o6u/2/

Comment: One issue with using borders is that we need set it color to body background color to maintain design integrity.

Comment: You can always set the border color to transparent.

Comment: Actually, you can use padding instead of border. You can add a left padding of 5px to the right div, and a right padding of 5px to the left div.

Comment: Will be correct this way for your second [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qwsgj6gc/1/)?

Comment: Rather than changing the width of your `div` and adding a border you can add an inner `div` with your desired padding. This `div`'s padding does not contribute to the width of its parent. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/L25ncraj/1/

Comment: Hmm, when test an actual layout (on desktop), the second image goes under the first, and text is on the right side of second picture. Firebug show that left div has wrong parameters (wrong width and padding): 
`.left {
    clear:right;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}` So CSS for left div has been overwritten for some reason.

Comment: This probably is because you are using percentages, and this is not always accurate. Tha's why I suggested the first method.